# Ruby Rails render form inheriting controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, url, inheritance, render

Hi and thanks in advance for any help.

I have an admin page: `views/admin/admin_page`

and a form located in: `views/videos/_new`

The form renders nicely inside of the `admin_page` however when I submit the form the url seems to inherit "admin" from either my `AdminController` or my `views/admin` folder and appends it to the url I specify in my form.  For instance the form below posts to `/admin/users/profile/videos`.

Can someone help me fix this, please?

```
    videos/_new.html.erb
    <%= form_for @video, url: 'users/profile/videos', controller: "videos", method: 'post', :html => { multipart: true } do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label :avatar %>
       <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit',class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

Routes:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users
        resources :users do
          resource :profile do
            resources :videos
          end
        end
      get 'admin/ad_pg', :to => 'admin#ad_pg'
    end

Rake Routes:

new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                          devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                          devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                         devise/sessions#destroy
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                     devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                    devise/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                         devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                         devise/passwords#update
                         POST   /users/password(.:format)                         devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                           devise/registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                          devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                             devise/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                  devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                  devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                  devise/registrations#destroy
                         POST   /users(.:format)                                  devise/registrations#create
     user_profile_videos GET    /users/:user_id/profile/videos(.:format)          videos#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/profile/videos(.:format)          videos#create
  new_user_profile_video GET    /users/:user_id/profile/videos/new(.:format)      videos#new
 edit_user_profile_video GET    /users/:user_id/profile/videos/:id/edit(.:format) videos#edit
      user_profile_video GET    /users/:user_id/profile/videos/:id(.:format)      videos#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/profile/videos/:id(.:format)      videos#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/profile/videos/:id(.:format)      videos#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/profile/videos/:id(.:format)      videos#destroy
        new_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/new(.:format)             profiles#new
       edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format)            profiles#edit
            user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)                 profiles#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)                 profiles#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)                 profiles#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)                 profiles#destroy
                         POST   /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)                 profiles#create
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                                  users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                                  users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                              users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                         users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                              users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                              users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                              users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                              users#destroy
                    root GET    /                                                 pages#home
                contacts GET    /contacts(.:format)                               contacts#index
                         POST   /contacts(.:format)                               contacts#create
             new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format)                           contacts#new
            edit_contact GET    /contacts/:id/edit(.:format)                      contacts#edit
                 contact GET    /contacts/:id(.:format)                           contacts#show
                         PATCH  /contacts/:id(.:format)                           contacts#update
                         PUT    /contacts/:id(.:format)                           contacts#update
                         DELETE /contacts/:id(.:format)                           contacts#destroy
             admin_ad_pg GET    /admin/ad_pg(.:format)                            admin#ad_pg
```

admin/ad_pg is my "admin page"

Thanks again,

Matt

Comment: What error shows?

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for responding.  The error I get is: 
No route matches [POST] "/admin/users/profile/videos"

Comment: Run `rake routes` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Posted the routes file too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matching route is `/users/:user_id/profile/videos(.:format)` but your url is `users/profile/videos` which has two problems. It is not absolute (it should start with a '/' and it does not include the `:user_id` segment). You should probably use the helper:

```
<%= form_for @video, url: user_profile_videos(user_id: @video.user_id), ...
```

Or something similar

Comment: Yes! it worked.  `form_for @video, url: user_profile_videos_path(current_user)`

Thanks